# Magento 2 products in cart from other session

Tags: magento2, cart, session

Strange behavior in **Magento 2.2.8**! When I leave the page for a few minutes and then do a refresh, products from other user sessions are in my cart! 20 minutes refreshing and there are 17 products in my cart and I didn't do anything. I do not use SID in the URL.

Update:
Disabling full page cache didn't work, added my env.php. The problem occurs on 2 sites, one in magento 2.2.8 and one in 2.3.1. Configuration is Nginx - Apache - Redis - php 7.1

Also, it didn't matter what kind of session caching I use (database, files or Redis)

```
'resource' => [
    'default_setup' => [
        'connection' => 'default'
    ]
],
'x-frame-options' => 'SAMEORIGIN',
'MAGE_MODE' => 'production',
'session' => [
    'save' => 'redis',
    'redis' => [
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'port' => '6379',
        'password' => '',
        'timeout' => '2.5',
        'persistent_identifier' => '',
        'database' => '2',
        'compression_threshold' => '2048',
        'compression_library' => 'gzip',
        'log_level' => '3',
        'max_concurrency' => '6',
        'break_after_frontend' => '5',
        'break_after_adminhtml' => '30',
        'first_lifetime' => '600',
        'bot_first_lifetime' => '60',
        'bot_lifetime' => '7200',
        'disable_locking' => '0',
        'min_lifetime' => '60',
        'max_lifetime' => '2592000'
    ]
],
'cache_types' => [
    'config' => 1,
    'layout' => 1,
    'block_html' => 1,
    'collections' => 1,
    'reflection' => 1,
    'db_ddl' => 1,
    'eav' => 1,
    'customer_notification' => 1,
    'config_integration' => 1,
    'config_integration_api' => 1,
    'full_page' => 0,
    'translate' => 1,
    'config_webservice' => 1,
    'compiled_config' => 1,
    'vertex' => 1
],
'install' => [
    'date' => 'Thu, 17 May 2018 11:30:44 +0000'
],
'cache' => [
    'frontend' => [
        'default' => [
            'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
            'backend_options' => [
                'server' => '127.0.0.1',
                'database' => '0',
                'port' => '6379'
            ]
        ],
        'page_cache' => [
            'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
            'backend_options' => [
                'server' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => '6379',
                'database' => '1',
                'compress_data' => '0'
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
];
```

Comment: Fresh installation? Do you install any third party caching module?

Comment: I use redis and did a refresh of i several times

Comment: Do you use varnish or FPC?

Comment: Yes, redis caching

Comment: @JilcoTigchelaar, is this in production? or the site in under development? this is due to temporary domain used across several projects may be.

Comment: It is a site in production....

Comment: Are you managing the customer session based on IP addresses?

Comment: I dont know, how can i see that?

Comment: can you please mention code of cache section of app/etc/env.php file

Comment: @SaphalJha i added the env.php and did some updates

Comment: Looks like, rediss cache is cause of this, you should remove the radis cache configuration then check, or should discuss with sever support.

Comment: If redis is switched of my site is so slow that it is not usable anymore...

Comment: Use magento build in cache or varnish instead of reddis + use CDN for speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a long search,but it was a problem with microcaching in engintron Nginx.

Ad this to your custom rules and the problem is gone

```
if ($SITE_URI ~* "yoursite.nl") {
   set $CACHE_BYPASS_FOR_DYNAMIC 1; # Disables micro-caching
   set $CACHE_BYPASS_FOR_STATIC 1; # Disables static file caching
}
```

Comment: So you are disabling engintron caching?

Comment: A part of the caching, micro caching

Answer (score 1):

If you are having this problem across multiple different installations using different versions of Magento, then I suggest it is an issue with caching on your local machine.

Please clear your browser cache directly from the browser settings and then close the browser. Empty temp directories. If CCleaner is installed, tick all of the cache/session options for your web browser and run CCleaner to clear up any files you might have missed.

Open your browser again and test the website.

If the problem persists, try again on a different browser with an empty cache after rebooting your machine. I've noticed that, with Firefox at least, some things are persistent which should not be persistent.

If you still get this problem, then disable all unnecessary modules, run `cache:flush`, `setup:upgrade`, `setup:di:compile` and `setup:static-content:deploy -f`.

Can you please provide an explanation of the process you use when you make a fresh installation?

***EDIT:***

Please could you try removing the redis settings from your env.php for only the session cache, but continue using redis for default and full page cache.

Although it is not exactly a solution, it should allow your site to load quickly without interfering with orders.

I would suggest that you raise this issue on the [Magento 2 github page](https://github.com/magento/magento2).

If you are following the standard server setup instructions and using a vanilla install of magento then it sounds more like a bug than a mistake you've made.

Comment: I cant ask al customers to clean their browser before they visit my webshops. Thats not an option, the deploy and static content rebuild i did several times but without succes

Comment: That is not what I meant. I simply meant that it could be an issue with the cache on your local development machine, but that users newly visiting your shop may not experience the same issue.

When you said you see cart items from other user sessions, I thought you meant you see items from user sessions that you have created yourself. Are you seeing cart items from sessions created by other people?

Comment: @JilcoTigchelaar please see my edited answer. Using redis for full page cache and default cache, but disabling it for session cache, should provide a workaround for the problem. You could look at running redis alongside memcached if you don't want to use varnish.

Comment: @joshau Flood, i also tried DB sessions and file session. In al the cases the problem continues...

Comment: @JilcoTigchelaar then please provide further information about your server configuration, database installation/configuration and magento installation/configuration.

There must be some commonality which causes this issue, else we would all be experiencing it.

Comment: i have a nginx - apache - redis config. I now switched of nginx and for now it looks good, but i want to wait a few days before i am sertain that it is nginx. Maybe some config

Comment: If you are happy with that solution, then perhaps you could consider using memcached instead of redis and see if that works alongside nginx.

Have you raised the issue on Magento's github?

Comment: One further thought... did you change `session.save_handler` to redis in your PHP configuration?